# How can I search my inbox for words in square brackets (like [ops])?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using the inbox quick search and typing in "Subject: [ops]" but it returns all emails with both "[ops]" as well as anything without the square brackets like "ops". What is the syntax for filtering email that only have the square brackets?

query:
subject: [ops]
results:
returns both [ops] and ops without brackets
expected results:
only shows messages with square brackets.

I know its possible since in the "advanced find" and "advance" tab I can select the field Subject with condition contains value [ops] and it only returns the right ones.

Query Advance:
Field: Subject
Condition: contains
Value: [ops]
results:
only shows messages with square brackets (as expected)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that Instant Search and Advanced Find use separate indexes. The Instant Search index ignores special characters. You cannot search for special characters with Instant Search.

Reference: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/389

Comment: its sad but it sure looks like you're right. thanks for the info as its been driving me crazy for a few days now :-)

Comment: Doesn't work since Outlook 2016. It seems that the advanced find search index now also ignores special characters.